# google map Cannot read property 'open' of undefined

Tags: javascript, google-maps

```js
$(document).on("click", "#searchRankingLocation", function() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {
            lat: 37.402040,
            lng: 127.107296
        }, //usepace
        zoom: 7
    });
    for (var i = 0; i < locationList.length; i++) {
        markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            draggable: true,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            position: locationList[i],
            title: rankingInfoList[i].name
        });
        infoList[i] = 'this area will changed.'

        windowNames[i] = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: infoList[i]
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'click', function() {
            windowNames[i].open(map, markers[i]);
        });

    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This is my source. 
I can't show you windows, I tried to find a lot of solution but they did not help me!

Comment: windowNames, markers, infoList are just array.

Comment: yeah, once the code is properly formatted it's much easier to read

Comment: the issue is the value of `i` once the click event happens ... it will be `locationList.length` - which is clearly wrong

Comment: sorry. this is my first question in stackoverflow.

Comment: umm... locationList is the array from the ajax in my database.

Comment: It's all good, this sort of question has been asked a few times on SO, but probably not easy to search for if you're new

Comment: I know what it  is, I'm talking about the value of `i` in `windowNames[i].open(map, markers[i]);` - you need a `closure` (typically an IIFE or create the listener in a function)

Comment: yes i am a newbie. i can't understand your answer

Comment: I was hoping to throw terms at you that you could use to search for an answer for yourself - instead I posted an answer with two possible solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your original code, the `var i` essentially makes the i variables scope outside of the loop, therefore by the time the click event happens, i would be `locationList.length` - so, obviously `windowNames[i]` would be undefined

3 ways to overcome this

using a function (I called it `doInfo` in this code )

```
$(document).on("click", "#searchRankingLocation", function() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {
            lat: 37.402040,
            lng: 127.107296
        }, //usepace
        zoom: 7
    });
    function doInfo(marker, windowName) {
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            windowName.open(map, marker);
        });
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < locationList.length; i++) {
        markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            draggable: true,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            position: locationList[i],
            title: rankingInfoList[i].name
        });
        infoList[i] = 'this area will changed.'

        windowNames[i] = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: infoList[i]
        });
        doInfo(markers[i], windowNames[i]);
    }
});
```

in this case, the function receives the current marker/windowName, so the value of `i` is now irrelevant

using an IIFE (Immediately invoked function expression)

```
$(document).on("click", "#searchRankingLocation", function() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {
            lat: 37.402040,
            lng: 127.107296
        }, //usepace
        zoom: 7
    });
    for (var i = 0; i < locationList.length; i++) {
        markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            draggable: true,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            position: locationList[i],
            title: rankingInfoList[i].name
        });
        infoList[i] = 'this area will changed.'

        windowNames[i] = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: infoList[i]
        });
        (function(x) { // the IIFE
            google.maps.event.addListener(markers[x], 'click', function() {
                windowNames[x].open(map, markers[x]);
            });

        })(i); //pass in the current value of i, used as x in the body of the IIFE
    }
});
```

This is very similar to the first case, just that the function is "inline" so could be considered more readable by some - `x` is the "captured" value of `i` for each iteration - alternatively you could also do

```
        (function(marker, windowName) { // the IIFE
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                windowName.open(map, marker);
            });

        })(markers[i], windowNames[i]);
```

So, you can see how this is almost identical to the first answer

Using ES2015 `let` - this will only work (without transpiling) in **modern** browsers (so, forget internet explorer)

```
$(document).on("click", "#searchRankingLocation", function() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {
            lat: 37.402040,
            lng: 127.107296
        }, //usepace
        zoom: 7
    });
    for (let i = 0; i < locationList.length; i++) {
        markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            draggable: true,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            position: locationList[i],
            title: rankingInfoList[i].name
        });
        infoList[i] = 'this area will changed.'

        windowNames[i] = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: infoList[i]
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'click', function() {
            windowNames[i].open(map, markers[i]);
        });
    }
});
```

`let i` means that each iteration of the loop, the value of `i` is "captured" for that iteration

again, this can also be done as:

```
        // ...
        let marker = markers[i];
        let windowName = windowNames[i];

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            windowName.open(map, marker);
        });
        // ...
```

So, you can see all methods are identical in end result when it comes down to it

Comment: i think you are a  genius. thank you so much much very muck.

Comment: I was troubled for two days. but you resolve the problem in short time.. thank you..amazing..