# Discord bot with js - for loop not working correctly

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, bots, discord

I am making a discord bot using js, but for some reason I can not get the bot to print an array properly via a for loop. The code is below

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const getJSON = require('get-json')
const BotToken = "tokenid";
const TwitchClientID = "?client_id=clientid";
const TwitchAPI = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/";
const bot = new Discord.Client();
var channelNames = ["channel1", "channel2", "channel3"];

bot.login('botloginid'); 

// !Live command that itterates through channelNames array and prints whether stream is currently live or not
bot.on("message", function(message) {
    if (message.content === "!Live") {
        for (var i = 0; i < channelNames.length; i++) { 
            getJSON(TwitchAPI+channelNames[i]+TwitchClientID, function(error, response) {
                if (response.stream == null) {                  
                    message.reply(channelNames[i] + ' is currently not live');
                } else {
                    message.reply(channelNames[i] + ' is currently live');
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

If I put in a message.reply('i is ' + i); before getJSON, it prints out 0 1 2, which is correct, but if I put message.reply('i is ' + i); after getJSON, it prints out, i is 3, i is 3, i is 3. And because the array indexes are 0,1,2 , returning 3 makes the bot display 'undefined is live/not live' rather than the name of the channel. I've never had a problem with loops in the past and I cant understand why it would be changing to 3 under getJSON and not even iterating as the loop is definitely working.

Comment: asynchronous code means `i` is `channelNames.length` (for all "iterations") by the time the callback for `getJSON` occurs .... fix by changing for loop to `for (let i = 0; i < channelNames.length; i++) {` - `let` instead of `var` changes the scope of `i`

Comment: similar situation to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44425708/5053002)

Comment: Ah, cool, I've always used an IIFE to solve this, I will switch to using `let`.